# Dynamic or flexible width of a parent div which can adjust according to its inner div columns in CSS

Tags: css

I have a div `#customers_table` which contains several `<div>` columns. I am not using any `<table>`, rather I make my inner divs behave like a table columns. These columns/data is coming from database. So the columns can be less or more depending on what you choose to add or remove in this web page.

I can't set a fixed width to `#customers_table` as I explained above we don't know in advance how many columns are going to display. So I wanted a horizontal scrollbar when the columns are enough to view in screen. The horizontal scrollbar will appear when the columns are out of viewpoint.

A sample extracted part of my HTML:

```
<div id="customers">

    <div id="customers_table">
    
        div columns
        div columns
        div columns
        ...
        ...
        ...
        
    </div>

</div>
```

To achieve this, I wrapped my `#customers_table` div within a parent div `#customers`. I have applied following CSS to these 2 divs:

```
#customers {
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width:100%;
}

#customers_table {
    border:1px solid red;
    min-width:1500px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

You can see that I am applying a `min-width` of 1500px. Though it does work when I add 2 or 3 more columns from my website. But when I add more and more columns the columns headers/divs are screwed up and break to second line.

Please see the screenshots below:

This is fine (when columns are less):

[image]

We can scroll through to see hidden data.

But when we add more and more columns then this issue arises:

[image]

I can't increase `min-width` since I don't know how many new columns will come in this table. So what is the solution to this problem so that the end result should match with my first screenshot irrelevant of the fact how many new columns a person can add?

Comment: Why would you need so many columns? From what I've seen of the first image, the header of each column clearly represents a unique category. The second image looks like there's a few repeated headers. The need for such a table eludes me....

Comment: @zer00ne ha sorry for confusion created. Actually I was just testing to see the layout when I will have many more columns added from my website functionality. They won't be repeated like these. I added them using web developer tool. But in real world, they will be unique coming from db. I hope it makes sense to you.